# How half screen option is implemented

Tags: ios

I notice in an application like "whatsapp", if you click on "tell friend" it display half screen options buttons, I wonder how these half screen options view is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an image, I'd say the half-view is a [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/).